# ta.cum(Value) reset on Condition - pinescript

Tags: pine-script, cumulative-sum, pine-script-v5

Is there a way to reset the count of ta.cum()?

-Current method
ta.cum(Value) reset on X bar_index

-Problem
On condition I am setting the "Value" to 0, but when it calls ta.cum(Value) again on the next bar its using the previous cum of all values before, I am looking for a way to reset the cum count

Comment: What is "Value"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whereevr you want to reset, you can keep a backup of ta.cum in another variable. And subtract that from actual cumulative value for all subsequent candles. Example below , where i am resetting at every 10th bar

```
//@version=5
indicator("Cumulative reset")

var prvsum=0.0
sum=ta.cum(close)
if bar_index%10==0
    prvsum:=sum
fixedsum=sum-prvsum
plot(fixedsum)
```